# Error when installing phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have installed XAMPP and am trying to set up the phpmyadmin so that I can install BambooInvoice. While going through the installation process for phpmyadmin, I get the following error. After hours of researching online I have still found no way of fixing it. Has anyone had this error and how did you fix it? Please help!

I attached a screenshot of the error that I am getting.

[Screenshot of the Error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncXt6.png)

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: Be sure to be installing our PPA version to have the latest one.
https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/wiki/DebianUbuntu#ubnutu-ppa
But the error seems to be that you are not using the right hostname when configuring phpMyAdmin